# How to work with git and a mobile semi-bare-repo?

Tags: git

I have a central git repository on my private server (the *--bare* one). Cloning and working with that is perfect.
That server is not reachable from the web! Web-access is no option for my repos.

When I'm go out of office then I copy my source code to my usb-stick and copy the content to the foreign pc again (because working directly on the usb-stick would be to slow).
After the work has been done on that pc the code must be copied back to the stick and later to the central main repository.

What I think about is what would be the best workflow in my situation?
Maybee the usb-stick should be a **--bare** repository too? The foreign pc would commit to it. But is it possible that the changes from the stick's repo can be merged to the central repository without any missbehaviour?

I hope I could explain my environment good enough.

Thank's for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using your USB drive as a bare repository is definitely a viable solution, and a fairly elegant one if you ask me. You can then push to it and fetch from it, just like with your central repository.

Git has pretty good supporting for multiple remote (in the broadest sense) repositories ("remotes"), so on your office PC you could simply add the USB drive as a second remote. Depending on your usage, you might sometimes have to use merges to get the two different remote synchronized again, but that's no different from normal merges. It makes no difference to Git, at least.

Here's a condensed example:

```
# setup bare repo on USB drive, e.g. using 'git clone --bare'
# on office PC
(work work work)
git remote add stick /path/to/repo/on/stick
git push stick <branches> # can use --all
# elsewhere
git clone /path/to/repo/on/stick
(work work work)
git push stick <branches>
# back in office
git fetch stick
(compare diffs or whatever you like)
git merge stick/mybranch
# etc.
```

PS. of course you can also use rebase if you prefer and know your way around it.